# How to find minimum and maximum row and column in a range that is passed as a parameter into a function

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to write special VLookup function in VBA where instead of one value that is looked up in a column range, multiple values are looked up in multiple columns ranges. When all the "lookup" values match the respective values in the columns, a value that is few specified columns away is returned. Something like

splvlookup (RngArea As Range, OptionName As String, StrikePrice As Single, TrdDate As Date, dcr As Integer, Columnref As Integer)

where

RngArea is the range of the total table

Name, Price, Dt  are values that are looked up in their respective columns in RngArea (Column numbers are not passed as parameters into the function as this is not necessary, the column headers do not change and all the columns are arranged in the same order always)

dcr is a decrement counter, this decrements the date by a few days. Thus, date which is looked up will be Dt -dcr

Columnref is a reference number which is the number of the columns from the first column in RngArea

In my table RngArea, there are multiple values for each of the variables Dt, Price, Name. However, there is only one unique combination of all three put together. The task is to find that unique row and find the corresponding value in the column identified by columnref.

My Question

How to find the minimum and maximum row and column ranges. Once I find this, I can use loops within these min and max ranges and check for the lookup values. I am sure this is a very simple trick for a pro but seems to be beyond me. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I used based on PA's advice, the code is fixed.

```
Function splVlookup(RngArea As Range, OptionName As String, StrikePrice As Single, TrdDate As Date, Datedecrement As Integer, Columnref As Integer) As Variant
Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While i < RngArea.Rows.Count + 1

If (RngArea.Cells(i, 9) = StrikePrice) And (RngArea.Cells(i, 3) = OptionName) And (RngArea.Cells(i, 1) = (TrdDate - Datedecrement)) Then

splVlookup = RngArea.Cells(i, Columnref)
Exit Function
End If

i = i+1

Loop

If i = RngArea.Rows.Count + 1 Then
splVlookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End If

End Function
```

Table structure is like this (delimited by '|')

TrdDate | Option |OptionName|Call Volume|Call Open.Int|Call Bid|Call Ask|Exp Date|StrikePrice|Put Bid|Put Ask|Put Volume|Put Open.Int

Comment: In your updated code, `Cells(ii, 9)` and others should be (eg) `RngArea.Cells(ii, 9)`  By itself `Cells()` will refer to the whole sheet, so you need to qualify it with the specific range you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks Tim, PA and B Hart. I had made some mistake in incrementing ii and ending the Do While loop in a Loop statement. Corrected it and now I am getting the correct answer. Thanks a ton. You guys rock!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `Range`, you can access its `.Rows.Count` and `.Columns.Count` and use simple `For` loops to iterate over its `.Cells` property.

```
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
  For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    set Val = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
  Next j
Next i
```

try this code with different ranges.

You will notice that `.Cells` refers to the cells contained in the Range relative to its origin. So, for `Range("B2:C4")`, its `.Cells(1,2)` will refer to `"C2"`.

It also copes with Ranges that contain non-contiguous cells. For `Range("B2:C4","D2:E4")`, its `.Cells(1,3)` will refer to `"D2"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, i and j cant start from 1. It has to start from the minimum row and min column range. And finding that is the challenge I am facing.

Comment: try the code I provided. `.Cells` refers to the cells contained in the `Range` relative to its origin. It also copes with Ranges that contain non-contiguous cells.

Comment: so, for `Range("B2:C4")`, its `.Cells(1,2)` will refer to "C2". And for `Range("B2:C4","D2:E4")`, its `.Cells(1,3)` will refer to "D2".

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the first and last cells in a range you can try something like the below:

```
Dim RR As Range
Set RR = Range("B2:D7")
MsgBox "First Cell: " & RR(1).Address & vbCrLf & _
    "Last Cell: " & RR(RR.Count).Address

'You can also use RR(#).Row or RR(#).Column if you need those values instead
```

If your trying to search for a Value within a Range take a look at the below routine and see if you can modify your code...

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox FindValue(Sheet1.Range("B2:D7"), "X")
End Sub

Function FindValue(RngArea As Range, strSearch As String)
Dim rCL As Range
Dim sFirstAddress As String
Dim rRES As Range

Set rCL = Nothing
Set rRES = Nothing
Set rCL = RngArea.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If rCL Is Nothing Then FindValue = CVErr(xlErrNA)
sFirstAddress = rCL.Address
Do
    If rRES Is Nothing Then
        Set rRES = rCL
    Else
        Set rRES = Application.Union(rRES, rCL)
    End If
    Set rCL = RngArea.FindNext(rCL)
Loop While Not rCL Is Nothing And rCL.Address <> sFirstAddress

FindValue = rRES.Address
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I posted a code that I wrote based on PA's advice. I am still doing something wrong.

Comment: I edited my code...  You may want to look at the RANGE.Find method to avoid looping through every cell in a range...  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks again. I am not sure I entirely followed the code. However, is the union method more efficient? In code clarity yes perhaps. But not sure the same holds in terms of the internal calculations the processor has to do. Even union must be resulting in an internal do loop. So how can it be more efficient? Just curious to know. Thanks.

Comment: I just added the application.Union for example sake...  All Union does is basically combine two ranges into one single range... So as a range matches the search criteria it will be added to the final range containing all the cells which match.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intersect and do a binary search:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const WS_MAX_ROWS = 1048576
Public Const WS_MAX_COLUMNS = 16384

Public Function rngMinRow(rng As Range) As Long
'   return the minimum row number within the extent of rng
'
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim mrow As Long
    Dim hrow As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim return_value As Long

    lrow = 1
    mrow = WS_MAX_ROWS \ 2
    hrow = WS_MAX_ROWS
    found = False
    return_value = -1

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Do While Not found
            If Not Intersect(Cells.Rows(lrow).Resize(mrow - lrow + 1), rng) Is Nothing Then
                If lrow = mrow Then
                    return_value = lrow
                    found = True
                Else
                    hrow = mrow
                    mrow = (lrow + hrow) \ 2
                End If
            Else
                If hrow - mrow = 1 Then
                    return_value = hrow
                    found = True
                Else
                    lrow = mrow + 1
                    mrow = (lrow + hrow) \ 2
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    rngMinRow = return_value
End Function
```

The above should work for any arbitrary range, and it does not iterate through the entire range nor does it use cells.count which can raise an error if there are more cells than the max value for a long integer. This should be pretty easy to adapt for rngMaxRow, rngMinColumn, and rngMaxColumn.